# Getting WP excerpt in a category.php outside of WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need some help pulling post excerpt out of the loop. I have few 'li's and  need to display excerpt while hovering them. If it was inside the loop it would no problem, but haw can I force WP to display an excerpt form a post's link currently hovered?

```
<ul>
WP loop BLAH BLAH
<li>(number of <li>s depending of number of posts in current category)</li>
end of loop
</ul>
<div>show excerpt from currently hovered li</div>
```

thanks in advance!

PS: I tried with get_the_excerpt function, but it displays only last post's excerpt..

Comment: What do these <li> elements contain?

Comment: I doesn't matter, It's only about hovering li and displaying div with correspondent excerpt.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why they aren't in the loop in the first place.

Comment: Because all excerpts are displayed in different position on page, wthout any relation to lis. Lis contain links to posts but post excerpts have to be displayed on the bottom, not inside of links, lis or even primary loop, below is the answer I needed, but I want to try to store all excerpts in array before displaying due to MortalViews's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the wp loop, the current post counter is incremented in every iteration. 
and the get_the_exceprt function will display the excerpt of the current post.

so when the loop is over and you get out of it, and you call the get_the_excerpt function, it will display the 'last post's excerpt as for it it's the current item.

solution:

you need to reset the loop using `rewind_posts()` function  before calling the get_the_excerpt function in new loop.

```
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
//....loop.
endwhile;

rewind_posts();

//start a new loop.
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$excerpt=get_the_excerpt();

endwhile;
```

or while you are in the first loop, store the excerpts in an array, and use after you get out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with rewind_posts(); function, I added some jQuery and it works lika a charm :)